# C# UTF-8 character encoding output - variable is different than string

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8

Here is a simple test case, I feel like I'm missing something basic but any help would be appreciated!

```
string data = @"Well done UK building industry, Olympics \u00a3377m under budget + boost";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(data, @"\\u(\w*)\b"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
    string match = m.Value;
    // These should output the exact same thing however the first is a £ and the other is \u00a3377m
    Console.WriteLine("\u00a3377m" + "      " + match);
}
```

Comment: Quite basic indeed. You're missing out on `@` turning `data` into a literal string. [A little brushing up on literals won't hurt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)

Comment: Sorry looking back I really didn't explain what I was trying to do very well, I was aware that I was making data a literal, I just did that so I didn't have \\u00a3377m which may of confused some people. What I was actually trying to do was have match output a £ sign like the string input manually, the way I achieved this in the end was using the function from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738282/replace-unicode-escape-sequences-in-a-string . Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the help, however it's my fault as I missed off some key information.

I actually wanted the output to be "£    £" rather than "£    \u00a3377m".

To do this I ended up using the answer from [Replace unicode escape sequences in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738282/replace-unicode-escape-sequences-in-a-string) which was to use the following function:

```
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"\\u(?<Value>[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public string Decoder(string value)
{
    return _regex.Replace(
        value,
        m => ((char)int.Parse(m.Groups["Value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString()
    );
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
string data = @"Well done UK building industry, Olympics \u00a3377m under budget + boost";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(data, @"\\u(\w*)\b"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
    string match = m.Value;
    //Decode the string so we no longer have \u values
    match = Decoder(match);
    // These should output the exact same thing however the first is a £ and the other is \u00a3377m
    Console.WriteLine("\u00a3377m" + "      " + match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the string you are printing manually. Hence the special character '\u00a3377m' is resolved directly.

The following works as desired:

```
// These should output the exact same thing however the first is a £ and the other is \u00a3377m
            Console.WriteLine("\\u00a3377m" + "      " + match);
```

Another option is using the @:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\u00a3377m" + "      " + match);
```

Answer (score 0):

`00A3` is unicode of `£` character. Take a look http://unicode-table.com/en/#00A3

So, when you try to write "`\u00a3377m"`, [*regular string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will be `£377m`.

Use *verbtaim string literal* instead like;

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\u00a3377m" + "      " + match);
```

> I completely forgot to add to the question that I actually wanted the
>   £ sign

```
char c = '\u00a3';
string s = c.ToString(); // s will be £
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I completely forgot to add to the question that I actually wanted the £ sign and not the literal. I will answer the question explaining how I did it.

Comment: That looks like a nice solution, I didn't realise the .ToString function could be used in that way! Thanks for the information.