# using a variable for the format string in String.Format, when it includes \n

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to read a line from a file, and use that line as the format specifier for a string.

The line in the file contains a newline character escape sequence \n. so it may look like this:

> ```
> Hello{0}\n\nWelcome to the programme
> ```

And I want to use it in a situation like this:

```
string name_var = "Steve";    
string line = ReadLineFromFile();
string formatted_line = String.Format(line, name_var);
```

Unfortunately, the result looks like:

> Hi Steve\n\nWelcome to the programme

Whereas I'd like it to look like:

> Hi Steve
>
> Welcome to the programme

Any ideas?

Comment: Would `.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)` work?

Comment: Should be `.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: @Complexity that doesn't work.

Comment: thanks @Stijn and amnezjak - that was the right direction to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `\n` in your string with the newline specifier like this:

```
string name_var = "Steve"; 

string line = ReadLineFromFile();
line = line.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);

string formatted_line = String.Format(line, name_var);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use escape sequences such as `\n` in your C# program, the compiler processes the string, and inserts the code of the corresponding non-printable character into the string literal for you.

When you read a line from a file or from another import source, processing of escape sequences becomes your program's responsibility. There is no built-in way of doing it. If all you want is `\n`, you could use a simplistic

```
formatString = formatString.Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

If you would like to support other escape sequences, such as ones for UNICODE characters, you could [use solutions from answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9738282/335858).