# Insert \u2265 into a C# string

Tags: c#, string, char

I have a data source that contains a `\u2265`, which is the greater or equal sign appearing as a single character just like this: `≥`

However when the data reaches my application it comes in as `\\u2265`.

I'm not concerned right now with why the extra `\` is occurring.

Instead I just want to be able to convert the `\\u2265` to a `\u2265` inside my application.

I have tried various string manipulations such as these, and they either had syntax problems, or simply didn't work:

```
disp = dataSource.Replace('\\', '\');  
disp = dataSource.Replace("\\", "\");
```

and

```
int x = dataSource.IndexOf("\\u");
disp = dataSource.Substring(0, x) + dataSource.Substring(x+1);
```

Part of the problem with the Substring technique is that `\\` is being seen as a single character.

Comment: Your two screenshots show the exact same code - so how are you seeing different results? Also, how is the data getting to your application? (Basically, we'll need more context in order to help.)

Comment: \ is an escape character, so when you see `"\\"` there's actually only 1 \ in the string.

Comment: I am not sure I am following, just adding the char to the string should work.  [See here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f0v8BU)

Comment: Thanks @Stijn for the edit.

Comment: I think the second screen shot shows `disp` after `disp = dataSource` whereas the first one shows `disp` right before that.

Comment: It looks like the screenshots are confusing the issue. I'm going to get rid of them.

Comment: @dev1998 The screen shots actually help me...

Comment: I think a [mcve] might help.

Comment: @dev1998 Look at my comment and the link.  Your code should work 100% as expected.  If its not, you need to give us a [MCVE]

Comment: @maccettura the problem is that his dataSource is bringing it in as a string, not a char

Comment: @maccettura, The problem is that the incoming data is where the problem is, but I can't easily do anything about that right now. I'm just trying to recognize the \\u and fix that so it is a \u.

Comment: @MikeH Yeah but OP's original screenshot shows `disp` being completely overriden with the value of `dataSource`.  OP's problem is _very_ unclear

Comment: What is _"a data source that contains a `\u2265`"_?  When you read it, do you see a string like _"x \u2265 y"_, with the backslash doubled up when you look at it in the debugger?  If so, that's not the same as _"x ≥ y"_.  The latter has a ≥ character in it, the former has that character represented as a six character string.  Have you tried substituting "≥" for "\u2265"?

Comment: @dev1998 you simply can't convert `\\u2265` into `≥` by replacing ``\\`` with ``\``.. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738282/replace-unicode-escape-sequences-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your data source has the `\u2265` as a `string` and is not treating it as a `char`.  If you replace the `string` version with a `char` version you'll get what you need.

```
data = data.Replace("\\u2265", '\u2265'.ToString());
```

The reason for the `ToString()` is so that we can use the appropriate overload for `Replace`.

Simpler version supplied by @Flydog57:

```
data = data.Replace("\\u2265", "\u2265");
```

General version inspired by @Jimi:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\\u[0-9]{4}");
var matches = r.Matches(data);
var uniqueMatches = matches
      .OfType<Match>()
      .Select(m => m.Value)
      .Distinct();

foreach (var m in uniqueMatches)
{
  data = data.Replace(m,Regex.Unescape(m));
}
```

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this down.  This is what I'd guess (from the little information in the original post) is the issue (well, with an edit to make it compile).  +1 from me.

Comment: Instead of `'\u2265'.ToString()`, you could have just said `"\u2265"`.

Comment: I'll try this, stand by.

Comment: Dont know how I missed the `ToString()`, my bad

Comment: @Flydog57 You're correct with the `"\u2265"`.  I'll update

Comment: I can see now that my question was not clear enough. This answer certainly does work, but I actually need something more generic. It is possible that some code other than 2265 will be in the data.

Comment: @dev1998 Sure, as long as there's a general form you can search and replace. Will it always be of the form `"\\uxxxx"`?

Comment: @MikeH yes \\uxxxx will be used.

Comment: @MikeH, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dev1998 Jimi's answer has it.

Comment: @dev1998 I've added a version that should avoid unexpected "unescaping"

Answer (score 3):

Another option, of more general use (but not always applicable, it might *interfere* with the string content) is to unescape the string using [Regex.Unescape()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
string myString = "\\u2265" + "20180426";
myString = Regex.Unescape(myString);
```

will print

```
≥20180426
```

Comment: Nice! The last piece to the puzzle is the `Unescape`.  I couldn't come up with it!

Comment: @MikeH  Yes, but it could mess with the string content. If the content is just what is shown here, it can work.

Comment: I think updated my version (shamelessly borrowing from you) avoids the mess.  +1 from me though.

Comment: The next problem I had was to decide between your answer and @MikeH as being correct. I decided to go with MikeH because of the way it looked for the unique matches. However both answers were up voted by me. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Absolutely. @MikeH Made all the *hard work*. Anyway, this is your question, you don't need to justify your choices :)